# Need help with selecting a color pallets for light and dark modes o a site

Tags: website-design, interface-design

I'm building a e-commerce site as part of a project and to make it more catchy, wanted to add a dark mode to my site. And, also I'm open to suggestions on the colors used for light theme built currently.

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/AELWity) are my site's screenshots loaded onto imgur as there are multiple images. (**Note:** SMH, Imgur says that you should be adult to view them, worry not, they aren't any NSFW images).

Currently, colors used are

- `Text` - black.
- `price`, `slider`, `location title`, `Buttons`, and `icons` - #ab7a5f
- `Button text color` - white

PS: Ain't a designer, open for any type of suggestions.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Colour choice is subjective, and idea gathering is generally off-topic here.  Questions like this can't really be answered objectively. So, I'm voiting to close it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Try: https://coolors.co/

Answer (score 0):

What I can suggest is not your palette, that is a choice that you and your client or team, or you alone, can make.

The suggestion sounds like a company slogan. Just try it.

[image]

If you made your CSS correctly this test will take you 30 seconds. The brown color works fine enough but probably needs a bit of adjustment to be used as text.

---

If your company has only 1 institutional color, then you can define additional colors, either using some tools or methods, like finding complementary colors, harmonies, triads, or whatever. There are some online tools that use these methods like https://paletton.com/#uid=10q0u0khenQ7oB6cbsTlDjFqWeh

So go and try it.